# Why does CO2 have a greater affinity for hemoglobin than oxygen?

Tags: solubility, biochemistry, oxidation-state, chemical-biology

I know about CO but I am wondering if CO2 has similar mechanism? do you guys have any scientific reference

> These species help form interactions between amino-acid residues at the interfaces of the four subunits in hemoglobin.  These interactions are called "salt bridges," because they are between positively-charged and negatively-charged amino-acid residues on different subunits of the same protein.  When "salt bridges" form, the subunits are held in a position that "tugs on" the histidine that is attached to the heme iron.

This is taken from here
[http://www.chemistry.wustl.edu/~edudev/LabTutorials/Hemoglobin/MetalComplexinBlood.html](http://www.chemistry.wustl.edu/%7Eedudev/LabTutorials/Hemoglobin/MetalComplexinBlood.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of this second paragraph of text?

Comment: @orthocresol♦ this is all what I found about it but I want to know if they compete on the same binding site? do they have a effect on if CO2 present or not when Oxygen is being transferred to the blood?

Comment: You can't just quote a paragraph of text without any context. Where is it taken from? What is it trying to describe? It's not even clear what the first two words, i.e. "These species", refers to.

Comment: @orthocresol♦ above a link

Comment: Before asking *why* something happens, it is usually worth asking *whether* it happens. Though carbon dioxide is bound by haemoglobin, oxygen displaces it (look up the Haldane Effect) so the premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: See this paper: https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(19)45105-3/pdf